# Can I set up a web form that will populate an opportunity in my salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities

I have a site I sent my clients to who want to move forward with our order process and I want the information they submit to automatically fill in the form under the opportunity. I was wondering how this was possible. I know you can set up a web to lead form but I dont see this option for what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native Opportunity feature equivalent for Web-to-lead or Web-to-Case.  You do have a lot of options though (ordered from simplest to most complex).

1. Use an app on the [AppExchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com) that provide web-to-x functionality.
2. Use a [pre-built connector](http://www.salesforce.org/integrating-salesforce-crm-and-wordpress-cms/) for popular CMS apps to integrate with Salesforce.
3. Create a Visualforce Page hosted on [Force.com sites](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Sites) and then embed that on your website
4. Create an [Apex Web Service](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_integration_services/units/apex_integration_webservices) hosted on Force.com sites that can be posted to by your form
5. Write code on your web platform to post to the Salesforce API.

Comment: Is this still accurate (2020)?